# How can I set session details in conftest.py for yield along with fixture in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, yield, fixtures

My aim is to create a pretest and post test in *conftest.py file* which will run after each test case in my test suite. i.e. I was trying to run the methods *(login_page() and login())* before all tests and the methods *(logout())* after all tests.

I have tried using the below code snippet

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def pretest():
    login_page()
    login()
    yield driver
    logout()
```

I have observed that, while my pre-tests (login_page() & login()) are running perfectly, before all test cases, post-tests (logout()) are not working as intended and was running *only* after all my selected test cases were executed.

To try a different approach, I had tried using the below code snippet in *conftest.py* as well

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def pretest():
    login_page()
    login()
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def posttest():
    logout()
```

The above method was simply throwing some errors and was not launching the test as such.

I had also tried the below code snippet in *conftest.py* file

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def pretest():
    login_page()
    login()
    yield driver
    logout()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're really close, and your issue comes from using the `"session"` scope, which is the higher possible scope (see more in [Pytest fixture scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session)).

Using `"session"` means your fixture is executed once for all the test run. If you're `yield`-ing in that fixture, what comes before the `yield` will be executed before all tests (not before each test!), and what comes after will run after all tests have run.

Switching this to `"function"` instead will make the fixture run before/after each test instead, which is what you want:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def login_context():  # Renamed for clarity
    login_page()
    login()
    yield driver  # Not sure what this is?
    logout()
```

Note the rename here: `pretest` is misleasing because part of the fixture will actually be executed after the test.